# How can I specify a file name for my attachment with Paperclip?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, paperclip, attachment

I have byte streams on the server that I'd like to attach to a model class with Paperclip, and I'd like to be able to specify the name that they're saved as on the filesystem.  Because I have a lot of these incoming files, I'd prefer to be able to create them as `Tempfiles` so that I don't have to worry about name collisions and deleting them manually and such.  This is what I'm doing:

```
desired_file_name = 'foo.txt'
Tempfile.open([File.basename(desired_file_name), File.extname(desired_file_name)]) do |tf|
  tf.write(content_stream)
  tf.rewind
  model_obj.paperclip_attachment = tf
end
```

That pretty much works.  The only problem is, my Paperclip attachment ends up with a tempfile name like foo.txt.201029392u-gyh-foh96y.txt.  So how can I tell Paperclip what to save my file as?  Calling `model_obj.paperclip_attachment_file_name = desired_file_name` doesn't work.  The DB field gets saved as that name, but on the filesystem I still have that tempfile name.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think you can define your own interpolation [interpolation](https://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip/wiki/Interpolations) to do that. You can then attach the file normally. For example:

```
# config/initializers/paperclip.rb
Paperclip.interpolates :custom_filename do |attachment, style|
  # Generate your desired file name here.
  # The values returned should be able to be regenerated in the future because
  # this will also be called to get the attachment path.

  # For example, you can use a digest of the file name and updated_at field.
  # File name and updated_at will remain the same as long as the file is not 
  # changed, so this is a safe choice.
  SHA1.sha1("#{attachment.original_filename}-#{attachment.updated_at}")
end

# app/models/post.rb
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_attached_file :attachment,
    :path => ':rails_root/public/system/:class/:attachment/:id/:style/:custom_filename',
    :url => '/system/:class/:attachment/:id/:style/:custom_filename'
end
```

Note that this only changes the file name in the file system. `model.attachment_file_name` or `model.attachment.original_filename` will still keep the original file name.

Comment: Thanks, this worked!  The only thing that I don't quite understand (and that I did not implement) is why you suggested using the hash function.  I'd like to preserve the desired_file_name.  The path of the file, which includes the id, should ensure uniqueness.

Comment: The hash function is to make the filename not guessable, so people can't just guess the URLs (attachment/1, attachment/2, etc) and download all the files. Using id plus file name should also achieve the same thing, but the advantage of using hash for me is that there's no characters that have to be URL escaped.